# error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using linq in a simple console application and I get this error and can't figure out what is wrong. Never got this error before with linq.

```
public class Program
{
    public static List<string> names = new List<string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        names.Add("Ruben");
        names.Add("Dirk");
        names.Add("Jan");
        names.Add("Klaas");

        var test = names.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith("k"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error message shown in your screen shot seems completely different to your title. Which error are you asking about? (However, be advised that both error messages are reasonably clear so please explain what you find confusing about them)

Comment: Both Ruben and Jan end with "n".

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netcore-3.1) . You have 2 elements that ends with a "n" so it's normal (`InvalidOperationException` is thrown if "The input sequence contains more than one element")

Comment: I edited the post, sorry I used the wrong letter in my example. Now you can see there is only 1 that matches the criteria and it gives me an error. Can you explain why this is? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I paste your code into VS and there is no error.

Comment: You should unaccept my answer below and accept @KlausGütter's, since that one explains what is actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` variable is only visible within the LINQ expression itself. So while the debugger is on the assignment statement `var test = names.SingleOrDefault...` you won't see it.
You can set a breakpoint on `x.EndsWith("k")` then you will see the x value when it is hit.

Comment: Since your answer is the correct explanation of what is happening, and mine is accepted, I'm gonna edit my answer to include your's, to provide the correct details to an accepted answer, with your permission. Is it ok?

Comment: I confirmed this answer now @HasanManzak

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal. It happens when predicate parameter is optimized out when code is compiled and not available to the debugger. When you continue to run the highlighted statement you should see the `test` variable is evaluated, if there're no other exceptions, which I'm referring to `SingleOrDefault()` call, it throws an exception when you have multiple results of the predicate test.

And also, as @klaus-gütter mentioned the variables in LINQ expressions are visible in the expression execution only, when they're not optimized out.